# VimのFileTypeについて

Tags: vim

Vim scriptで以下のようなコードを書き、開くファイルによって挙動を変えようと試みました。
しかしこのコードを`.vimrc`に書きVimを起動させましたが、`Python`のファイルを開いても
`g:vim_standard_format`が1のままになってしまいます。

この件について十分に調べたつもりではありますが、`autocmd`を使用して変数に代入している例が
あまり無く、自分だけでは解決できそうにないので質問させていただきました。

どなたかご教示いただけますでしょうか。

```
filetype plugin indent on
let g:vim_standard_format = 1
autocmd FileType python let g:vim_standard_format=0

echo g:vim_standard_format
```

念のため自身の環境も載せておきます。

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5LTS

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Aug  4 2017 01:55:49)
適用済パッチ: 1-851
Huge 版 with GTK2 GUI.  機能の一覧 有効(+)/無効(-)
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      -terminal
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xpm
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
```

Comment: pythonファイルを開いた**後**で`:echo g:vim_standard_format`を実行しても1のままだったということでしょうか。そうではなくて、上記のコード全体がそのままvimrcに含まれていて、それによる出力を見たのだとすれば、FileType pythonが起きる前の値になるので、1のままです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。  そういうことだったんですね。  Vimを開いた後に`:echo g:vim_standard_format`を実行すると確かに0になりました。  vimrc内でどの拡張子のファイルが開かれたかを区別する方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: "vimrc内でどの拡張子が開かれたかを区別する方法"は、ないとは言いませんが、"編集を始めたファイル名"の拡張子、といった条件付きになります。。拡張子を区別してそのあとに何がしたいかを教えていただけると答えやすいです。

Comment: すみません。返事遅れてしまいました。 *.pyを開く時と*.cppを開くときでコード整形のコマンドを変えたいと思っています。*.pyのファイルをコード整形する時にgg=Gだと私の環境ではうまく機能してくれなかったので、[ton-tech-tonさんのページ](http://ton-up.net/technote/2013/11/26/vim-python-style-check-and-fix/)を参考に*.pyの時だけgg=GでAutopep8を呼び出すようにしたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VimでPythonファイルを編集するときに、`gg=G`の整形でautopep8を使う方法、として回答します。

vimrcに下記の内容を書くことで実現できます。

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal equalprg=autopep8\ -
```

（pythonのとき、vimの`=`コマンドで使う外部プログラムとしてautopep8を指定するという内容です）

Comment: 申し訳ございません、帰省をしており返信遅れました。  回答ありがとうございます。  こちらで上記の内容を確認したところ、求めていた動作をしてくれました。  ありがとうございました。

Comment: @山元清矢 さん、お役に立てて幸いです。課題が解決できた場合は、解決に最も役立った回答に「承認」のチェックを入れるのがこのサイトのルールとなっております。課題解決後には必ず承認をお願いいたします。

Comment: 夜分遅くに申し訳ございません。  すみません、ルールを知りませんでした。  たった今チェックを入れさせていただきました。  この度は大変ありがとうございました。